# Collection View Button Action (Cocoa, Xcode)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, button, collectionview

In XIB file I have a collection view which contains a button. In awake from Nib i have defined several of buttons with different images. So the application basically looks like a finder, but does not perform any actions yet.

What I want to do now, is that when pressing each button a different file opens (I use filemanager method). I can do this easily in non-collection view type application, but when using collection view I am not sure how to attach different action to each button.

This is what I have, but that would open the same pdf.pdf for every button, when I want every button to open different pdf.

```
@implementation AppController
-(void) awakeFromNib {


MyButton *Button1 = [[MyButton alloc] init];
Button1.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"img1"];


MyButton *Button2 = [[MyButton alloc] init];
Button2.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"img2"];

MyButton *Button3 = [[MyButton alloc] init];
Button3.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"img3"];

_modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[controller addObject:Button1];
[controller addObject:Button2];
[controller addObject:Button3];}

- (IBAction)OpenCVFile:(id)sender {


NSFileManager *fileManagerCv = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString *filePath = @"Users/Tom/pdf.pdf";

if ([fileManagerCv fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSLog(@"File exists");
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]openFile:filePath withApplication:@"Finder"];}
else {
    NSLog(@"File does not exist");

}
}
```

Could anyone help?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what kinds of actions do you need to perform upon clicking each button?

Comment: @RenfeiSong is it clearer now? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Bindings**

First off, introduce a property to your model class that points back to the controller.

For example, a very simple model class would be:

```
@interface ModelData : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property id controller;

@end

@implementation ModelData
@end
```

Initialize your collection view's `content`:

```
// In the controller
ModelData *data1 = [ModelData new];
data1.name = @"Apple";
data1.controller = self;

ModelData *data2 = [ModelData new];
data2.name = @"Boy";
data2.controller = self;

[self.collectionView setContent:@[data1, data2]];
```

In interface builder, select the button in your prototype `Collection View Item`, navigate to the **Bindings Inspector**, create bindings for `Argument` and `Target`:

- For `Argument`, set `Bind to` to `Collection View Item`, then set the `Model Key Path` to any property in your model class that you can use to uniquely identify the button (e.g. `representedObject.name`), and set the `Selector Name` to your action method's signature, say `buttonClicked:`.
- For `Target`, set `Bind to` to `Collection View Item`, then set the `Model Key Path` to something that points to your controller class (where the action method is implemented), and set the `Selector Name` the same as above.

[image]
[image]

After these two bindings are set up, your action method in the controller class will be called with the argument you designated when the button is clicked.

```
// In the controller
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)anArg {
    NSLog(@"%@", anArg);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the represented object pdf.pdf does not get attached to the end of filePath and therefore NSLog is /Users/Tom/(null)

Comment: Could that be, because I am using AwakeFromNib?

Comment: @ShaunArchibald How did you populate your `NSCollectionView`? Did you use bindings?

Comment: @RanfeiSong Yes I did. To me it seems like 
   [ [button cell] setRepresentedObject:@"pdf.pdf"];
This does not work

Comment: @ShaunArchibald So if I understand you right you are adding your buttons to _each_ of your collection view items (i.e. to the prototype item's view), from the interface builder?

Comment: @ShaunArchibald I got it. Updated my answer.

Comment: @RanfeiSong Thanks for the answer, it works!

However, after pressing the button once in the ouput it shows as if I pressed it twice and it seems that xcode was unable to trace the file firstly, but then it did it again and it worked: 

2015-05-31 23:09:32.622 Collection View with Buttons[16509:868627] File does not exist
2015-05-31 23:09:32.637 Collection View with Buttons[16509:868627] File exists

Comment: @ShaunArchibald Hard to say what's going on - I set up the aforementioned bindings myself and the method gets called exactly one time every time I click the button. Maybe the other invalid call wasn't from the bindings?

Comment: Do you also happen to know in this case how to make a button selected (blue border line lights up) with one mouse click and invoke action with a double click. Is that possible to do in the XIB file?

Comment: @ShaunArchibald I am not sure I understand what you meant - what exactly is _selected_ for a button? I couldn't recall any cases where a normal button can have a blue outline. Also triggering an event with double-click isn't the Cocoa way of a button. It's certainly doable, but not likely in the interface builder.

Comment: Pardon my language @RanfeiSong yea indeed I'm talking about a focus ring. In my case the button is not a normal button, because what I am basically creating is a finder window with buttons. Each button corresponds to a different file and each of those buttons have a preview picture attached to them. You can then select any of those "buttons" and by double clicking you can open the file that the "button" corresponds to (for example a pdf file).

Comment: @ShaunArchibald I see. I would suggest you consider using the collection view's selection mechanism and render your subviews with a highlighted look when selected. Also buttons don't have a binding for double action. The easiest way I can think of now is to subclass it and override -mouseDown:.